# DAW not working when decreasing - assembly

Tags: assembly, pic

I am new to assembly using it for microcontroller PIC18F458. I am asked to show the counting sequences numbers 99 through 00 on Units and tens 7-segment.

I use the following code but DAW not working what should i do?

```
        ORG     0000H
COUNT   EQU     0X0FF   ; Use location 25H for counter
        CLRF    TRISB
R1      EQU     07
R2      EQU     08
R3      EQU     09
R4      EQU     10
        MOVLW   00H
        MOVWF   R1
REP1:
        MOVWF   PORTB
        CALL    DELAY
        INCF    PORTB,F
        MOVF    PORTB,W
        DAW
        GOTO    REP1
DELAY:
        MOVLW   D'20'
        MOVWF   R4
BACK:   
        MOVLW   D'100'
        MOVWF   R3
AGAIN:  
        MOVLW   D'250'
        MOVWF   R2
HERE:
        NOP
        NOP
        DECF    R2,F
        BNZ     HERE
        DECF    R3,F
        BNZ     AGAIN
        DECF    R4,F
        BNZ     BACK
        RETURN
        END
```

Comment: What *does* happen when you single-step through your code?  [edit] your question to make it a [mcve].  (And don't double-space your code, that makes it hard to read.)

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted does work the way you want.

What you seem to have missed is all the extra stuff needed to get the PIC18F458 "working" in the normal way.

This is your code that works in the MPLAB simulator:

```
;
;   Filename:       main.asm
;   Author:         dan1138
;   Target:         PIC18F458
;   Assembler:      MPASMWIN v5.22
;   Assembler mode: Absolute
;
;   Files required: p18f458.inc
;
;   Description:
;
;   Increment a BCD value in the PORTB output latch register.
;
    list P=18F458, r=dec, n=0, c=255
#include "p18f458.inc"
;
; Setup configuration words
    config OSC      = HS
    config BOR      = OFF
    config BORV     = 45
    config PWRT     = OFF
    config WDTPS    = 128
    config WDT      = OFF
    config STVR     = ON
    config LVP      = OFF
    config CP0 = OFF, CP1 = OFF, CP2 = OFF, CP3 = OFF
    config CPD = OFF, CPB = OFF
    config WRT0 = OFF, WRT1 = OFF, WRT2 = OFF, WRT3 = OFF
    config WRTD = OFF, WRTB = OFF, WRTC = OFF
    config EBTR0 = OFF, EBTR1 = OFF, EBTR2 = OFF, EBTR3 = OFF
    config EBTRB = OFF
;
;   /* Specify the System clock frequency in Hz */
#define FSYS 10000000

;   /* Specify the Peripheral clock frequency in Hz */
#define FCYC (FSYS/4)
;
; Power On Reset entry point
    org     0
    goto    start
;
; Interrupt Service Routine entry point
    org 0x08
ISR_vevtor:
    retfie  1
;
; Declare application RAM in access bank
 cblock 0x07
    R1:1
    R2:1
    R3:1
    R4:1
 endc
;
; Main application start
start:
    clrf    INTCON          ; Disable all interrupts
    movlw   0x07
    movwf   ADCON1          ; Make ADC analog inputs digital I/O pins
    movlw   0x07
    movwf   CMCON           ; Make comparator analog inputs digital I/O pins
;
; Main application loop
        CLRF    TRISB       ; Make PORTB pins digital output
        MOVLW   00H
        MOVWF   R1          ; Set RAM location R1 to zero, don't know why.
        MOVLW   00H         ; Load WREG with initial BCD value
REP1:
        MOVWF   LATB        ; Write the WREG to PORTB outputs
        CALL    DELAY       ; Wait for about one second with a 10MHz system clock
        INCF    LATB,W      ; Increment output latch, put result in the WREG
        DAW                 ; Adjust the value in WREG to be BCD
        GOTO    REP1        ; Do it again.
DELAY:
        MOVLW   D'20'       ; Delay for about one second.
        MOVWF   R4          ; You figure out how it works.
BACK:   
        MOVLW   D'100'
        MOVWF   R3
AGAIN:  
        MOVLW   D'250'
        MOVWF   R2
HERE:
        NOP
        NOP
        DECF    R2,F
        BNZ     HERE
        DECF    R3,F
        BNZ     AGAIN
        DECF    R4,F
        BNZ     BACK
        RETURN
    end
```